# Force AJAX Header Change

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

So I am developing a Apache Cordova app for Android, and I'd like to be able to set the headers for the AJAX requests I am sending, **including** the Host, Origin, and Referer fields. Because these are being executed in a separate WebView, I can't access the user's original cookies or sessions (I'm not being malicious, I promise). But whenever I attempt to send that information, I get a "Refused to set unsafe header Host" error. Is there any way to override this in Apache Cordova?

Comment: Host, Origin, Referer - these headers are usually set by the browser on behalf of you and as you can see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method), any attempt to set those headers will not fire the call at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a plugin that makes the request from native side. This approach will allow you to bypass the web view limitations on making request outside your origin.

You could start using this plugin: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.

Comment: Thank you for your response. In my particular situation, I have to send Cookies, so that plugin isn't ideal, but I could make it work with a few small modifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can try using the `headers` option when setting up the call. You can also use the `beforeSend` option if you need more fine-grained control over the headers.

```
//set specific accept headers (should work cross browser)
$.ajax({
headers: {
    Accept : "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
}
});

//an alternative to the above
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function(xhrObj)
    {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    }
    });
```

Comment: This is what I am already doing, the issue is that the browser itself refuses to set those headers. Is there a way to override that in Apache Cordova?

Comment: I know that Chrome won't allow you to set content-length for example. It does that for you. Also, you might be experiencing problems with cross-domain requests. If that's the case, you might want to try using 
`xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Origin","*");`

Comment: Apache Cordova blocks that. It says refused to set unsafe header origin.

Comment: Another possibility is by using a content type that the control isn't strictly enforced. With that, it seems by setting the Content-Type to plain/text, it should go through without a problem.
This has to do with avoiding "preflighted" requests, thereby allowing you to set these headers. Just be sure to properly manage these requests on the server side.

Comment: I unfortunately don't control the servers that I am requesting to.

Comment: Yet another way to override these restrictions would be to send the proper headers, as Chrome will take into account what the server says is allowed. You can set the access control headers however you want. For the example, I will show the php version I used a couple of times.

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");`

Comment: Again, the server is not one I control. I can't change the code on the server.

Comment: The server you're hitting needs to allow CORS: it needs to put a header Access-Control-Allow-Origin with the specified Origin in the request header, or *, when returning the data; otherwise your browser will reject it.
One last attempt (if you already didn't do so) would be to whitelist the server you're trying to access. See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html

Comment: I know about CORS, I am asking if there is a way to override it in this question. I don't need to get access to the current session in the user's browser, just mine that I just set with AJAX. I have whitelisted the domain.

Comment: I can't change what the server allows. And they are trying to setup an API, but they just aren't getting it done.